# Programatically instantiate and add controls to UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm creating a specific webpart in Sharepoint and I'm using (or trying to) AjaxToolkit controls.
Because of the environment I'm developing on, I can't declaratively write my webpart, so I have to do it all programatically.

I'm trying to add the UpdatePanel, but so far without success.

Here's my code:

```
internal void CreateMainPanel()
{
    Panel main = new Panel{CssClass="form"};
    UpdatePanel All = new UpdatePanel();
    All.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(main);
    //form is a static panel reference which I use inside the class
    form = main;
}
```

Then I get this message:

`[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: child]
   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) +11023974`

If I'm understanding it right, the error says my Panel is "null". Why so? I instantiated it right now.

How can I add the UpdatePanel and its controltemplate programatically?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add brackets after new Panel:

```
internal void CreateMainPanel()
{
    Panel main = new Panel(){CssClass="form"};
    UpdatePanel All = new UpdatePanel();
    All.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(main);
    //form is a static panel reference which I use inside the class
    form = main;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was elsewhere, but something related, so I'm marking as answer because it was closest to the problem.